# Windows 10 Build 15007 crash on lid close

Tags: laptop, bsod, windows-10-preview

My laptop crashes every time i close it since the last windows insider preview build. I know it's a preview and they are not supposed to be stable. I also had the problem described [here](http://windowsreport.com/fix-windows-10-build-15007-no-audio-cpu-edge-bugs/). But for the problem I have, I found no answer.

When I close my laptop and open it again my keyboard is still lit up and it and the the battary led's and so on as well, but the screen is black. I tried to put it into sleep and start again but it wont help. I have to force shutdown it to use it again. And for a laptop this is a serious problem.

I never had this problem before, as I said I have it since Windows Version: Windows 10 Insider Preview 15007 (rs_prerelease), installed on 13.01.2017

[Here are my specs](http://pastebin.com/WBYKhLYn). If you need more or other information just ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bug in Build 15007 which is [fixed in Build 15014](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/01/19/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-15014-for-pc-and-mobile-hello-windows-insiders-today-we-are-excited-to-be-releasing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-15014-for-pc-and-mobile/)

> **Other changes, improvements, and fixes for PC**
>
> - We fixed an issue some Insiders may have experienced where their laptops would bugcheck when closing the lid to put it to sleep.

So open Windows Update in the settings app and update to Build 15014 to get the issue fixed.